# Facebook online friend list with Graph API

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I trying to get friend list with chat status .active or not ı m using graph api.I want to use android and ios. I m trying to explore with Graph API explorer .but  its give me

```
     {
   "error": {
   "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (online_presence) on node type   (User)",
   "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100
    } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what API call you are trying to make, but what you want to achieve is not possible:

- There is no "online_presence" field in the user table (at least not anymore)
- friend permissions are deprecated

See the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: but I found app using this ,I want to get online friend list of user. but I read your link .I understand

Comment: of course it works in older apps (until april 2015), but not in new ones anymore. see the changlog. main point is: you can´t get the information anymore.